# imageAtomicExchange won't compile

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glsl, nvidia

I'm trying to use two opengl images, one of which is sparse and the other used as a sort of page table, in which I keep track of the page actually commited.

I have a simple little shader, which looks like this (main not included):

```
#version 450 core
#extension GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store : require

uniform float gridSize;
uniform float pageTableSize;

bool isPageInMemoryOrRequest (in ivec3 pos)
{
    bool returnValue = false;
    if ( 255u == imageAtomicExchange(pageTable, pos, 128u) )
    {
        returnValue = true;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

And my problem is that this won't compile. I keep getting this message:
**Error C1115: unable to find compatible overloaded function "imageAtomicExchange(struct uimage3D1x8_bindless, ivec3, uint)"**

I'm pretty sure I've never seen that _bindless part anywhere in the specs and I'm not exactly sure how the compiler figures out that is a bindless texture at compile time (or maybe they're all bindless in the latest drivers).

I've got a GTX660TI and I'm using the 352.86 drivers.
I'm wondering if anyone's had this sort of issue before and could tell me what might the problem be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly is that first argument?

Comment: It was a r8ui uimage3D, I see now that I forgot to add that, but the question was answered, so I'm glad that I didn't pay for that mistake this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the extension specification of [ARB_shader_image_load_store](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/imageAtomicExchange.xhtml) (Section 8.X, Image Functions), there is only of very limited number of supported formats for atomic operations:

> Atomic memory operations
>       are supported on only a subset of all image variable types;  must
>       be either:
>
> - an image variable with signed integer components (iimage*) and a
>         format qualifier of "r32i", or
> - an image variable with unsigned integer components (uimage*) and a
>         format qualifier of "r32ui".

I assume from the error message, that you have tried to use a r8ui format, which is not supported.

Comment: That was it, thank you, I really didn't see that in the spec. Cheers